# How can I construct a string to be read as unicode?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

I am trying to convert a 4-digit binary string into a hexadecimal digit (0-f), then combine several of these digits into a single Unicode string, that is then printed as a single ASCII character. This requires me to have "\" at the start of each Unicode character, but attempting to add the hexadecimal digits to "\" returns a "SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal.

Adding them instead to "\\" avoids the error, but the now formed Unicode string is printed as "\XXX" rather than as a single character.

print "\x3f" returns ?
print "\x3f" returns \x3f

Is there a way to dynamically construct Unicode strings by appending to a string?

Comment: Seeing sample input, desired output and the code thus far would help.

Comment: if you can use python 3 i believe they made all unicode handling more nice

Comment: You need to at least provide some sample data you want to convert, and expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not easy to understand what your input and outout should look like, but those function should help you achieve your goal :

```
>>> "1010"
'1010'
>>> int("1010",2)
10
>>> hex(int("1010",2))
'0xa'
>>> hex(int("1010",2))[2:]
'a'
>>> hex1 = hex(int("1010",2))[2:]
>>> hex2 = hex(int("0101",2))[2:]
>>> hex1+hex2
'a5'
>>> int(hex1+hex2,16)
165
>>> int("1010"+"0101",2)
165
>>> unichr(int(hex1+hex2,16))
u'\xa5'
```

Comment: Yes. -  my understanding of what is intended with the question is this.

On phrase how the u"\uXXXX" syntax is just a way of inputting the unicode, and don't exist like that in memory, as well as printing the unichr "repr" would improve this for the OP and other readers.

Comment: And, keeing this detailed data, just show that all is needed is unichr(int(bin1 + bin2 + bin3 + bin4, 2) )  for a 4-digit unicode char, of coruse.

Comment: @jsbueno: All true. I'll wait for some OP input though.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information, this is my first question >.<. Your reply has solved my issue, I worked it out from there. Thank you.

Comment: @LucaKollmer: No problem. For next time, an example of input and desired output is extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Without input and output examples, here's what I could come up with:

```
# Get our input from somewhere
binaries = [
    "0101", "0100", "0110", "1000", "0110", "0101", "0111", "0010",
    "0110", "0101", "0010", "0000", "0110", "1001", "0111", "0011",
    "0010", "0000", "0110", "1110", "0110", "1111", "0010", "0000",
    "0110", "0011", "0110", "1111", "0111", "0111", "0010", "0000",
    "0110", "1100", "0110", "0101", "0111", "0110", "0110", "0101",
    "0110", "1100"
]

# Convert the binary strings to numbers so we can do math
inters = []
for b in binaries:
    if type(b) is str :
        inters += [ int(b, 2) ]
    else:
        inters += [ b ]

i = 0
outstr = u''
while i < len(inters):
    # "add" the two together using bitwise or to get the
    # ordinal value of the character you're looking for
    b = inters[i] << 4
    b |= inters[i + 1]
    # Make sure the value of b is a valid ASCII character
    if b > 0 and b < 255:
        # append the character that matches value "b"
        outstr += u"{!s}".format(chr(b))
    else:
        # Add a "?" in the case of an illegal character value
        outstr += u"?"
    # increment our counter
    i += 2

print( outstr )
# u'There is no cow level'
```

## Revision

After jsbueno's comments, I think I see what OP is trying to do.  Dealing with multi-byte unicode seems to be tough.  Let's throw a multi-byte character into our string:

```
sample_string = u'\xa1There is no \xa2\u014fw level!'

# nibbles = [i for s in [[y[0:4], y[4:]] for y in ['{:08b}'.format(x) for x in map(ord, list(sample_string.encode('utf-8')))]] for i in s]

nibbles = [
    '1100', '0010', '1010', '0001', '0101', '0100', '0110', '1000',
    '0110', '0101', '0111', '0010', '0110', '0101', '0010', '0000',
    '0110', '1001', '0111', '0011', '0010', '0000', '0110', '1110',
    '0110', '1111', '0010', '0000', '1100', '0010', '1010', '0010',
    '1100', '0101', '1000', '1111', '0111', '0111', '0010', '0000',
    '0110', '1100', '0110', '0101', '0111', '0110', '0110', '0101',
    '0110', '1100', '0010', '0001'
]

# Make the list of nibbles (4 bits) into a list of bytes (8 bits)
bytelist = [ x[0] + x[1] for x in zip(nibbles[0::2], nibbles[1::2])]

# Make sure the bytelist is half the size of the nibble list:
len(nibbles) == len(bytelist) * 2
# True

# Change each byte in the bytelist into UTF-8 hex codes
hexlist = ['0x{:02x}'.format(int(y, 2)) for y in bytelist]

# create a list of integers from hex string values
intlist = [int(x, 0) for x in hexlist]

# Print it out!
print(''.join(chr(x) for x in intlist))

# Or, you can convert it into unicode:
unistr = unicode(''.join(chr(x) for x in intlist), 'utf-8')
print(unistr)
```

All this can be compressed to the following:

```
def decodeNibbles(nibbles):
    if len(nibbles) % 2 != 0:
        raise ValueError('Uneven number of nibbles given')
    unistr = ''.join(
            chr(int('{:s}'.format(y), 2))
            for y in [ x[0] + x[1] for x in zip(nibbles[0::2], nibbles[1::2])]
        )
    return unistr

nibbles = [
    '1100', '0010', '1010', '0001', '0101', '0100', '0110', '1000',
    '0110', '0101', '0111', '0010', '0110', '0101', '0010', '0000',
    '0110', '1001', '0111', '0011', '0010', '0000', '0110', '1110',
    '0110', '1111', '0010', '0000', '1100', '0010', '1010', '0010',
    '1100', '0101', '1000', '1111', '0111', '0111', '0010', '0000',
    '0110', '1100', '0110', '0101', '0111', '0110', '0110', '0101',
    '0110', '1100', '0010', '0001'
]

decodedString = decodeNibbles(nibbles)
print(decodedString)
# ¡There is no ¢ŏw level!
```

Comment: Nice code, but what I believe the OP wants is simply to print char u"\u030f" given the binary strings for 0, 3, 0 and f.

Comment: _that is then printed as a single ASCII character_  
That makes me think he wants a string output.  Need examples!

Comment: I think I now see what you mean!  I'll amend my answer shortly.

Comment: Just an aside: half-bytes (4 bits) are called nibbles.  I love IT geekery :D